# Can the search box be stopped from covering the navigation toolbar?

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a search box which automatically moves into the navigation toolbar area and completely covers it when tapping inside the search box.

This means I cannot tap on toolbar buttons to perform actions based on the search results, like I can when not doing a search.

Is there any way to reposition the search box when the user taps on it to start a search, other than covering the navigation toolbar?

Here is my code:

```
struct MemoryPalaceView: View {

@State private var addToMemoryPalaceIsPresented: Bool = false
@State private var duplicateIsPresented: Bool = false
@State private var nativeThing: String = ""
@State private var foreignThing: String = ""
@State private var queryString = ""
@State private var duplicatedNative = ""
@State private var duplicatedForeign = ""
@State private var duplicatedMemoryPalace = ""
@State private var deleteMemoryPalaceThingIsPresented = false
@State var editMode = EditMode.inactive
@State var selection = Set<MemoryPalaceThing>()
@State private var playEntireList: Bool = false
@State private var changeVoiceSpeed: Float? = 0.25
@State private var numberSpeechLoops: Int? = 1
@State private var editMemoryPalaceIsPresented: Bool = false
@State private var memoryPalaceThing: MemoryPalaceThing?
@State private var emptyDataMessage: NSMutableAttributedString?

@ObservedObject var canvasColor = CanvasTintColor()
@ObservedObject var aurotorial = Aurotorial()
@ObservedObject var core = Core()

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(entity: MemoryPalaceThing.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "foreign", ascending: true)]) var memoryPalaceThings: FetchedResults<MemoryPalaceThing>
@FetchRequest(entity: MemoryPalace.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var memoryPalaces: FetchedResults<MemoryPalace>
@FetchRequest(entity: SectionThing.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var sectionThings: FetchedResults<SectionThing>

let noMemoryPalaceThingsAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
]

var memoryPalace: MemoryPalace
var language: Language
var loopSpeechSynthesizer: [Int] = [1,3,6,9,12]

var filteredMemoryPalaceThings: [MemoryPalaceThing]? {
    if queryString.isEmpty {
        return memoryPalace.memoryPalaceThing?.allObjects as? [MemoryPalaceThing] ?? []
    } else {
        let memoryPalaceThings = memoryPalace.memoryPalaceThing?.allObjects as? [MemoryPalaceThing] ?? []
        return memoryPalaceThings.filter { $0.native?.prefix(queryString.count).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(queryString) ?? true || $0.foreign?.prefix(queryString.count).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(queryString) ?? true }
    }
}

var searchablePrompt: String {
    var prompt = ""
    
    if filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count ?? 0 < 2 {
        prompt = "Add 2 '\(memoryPalace.name ?? "")' words to search"
    } else {
        prompt = "Search \(languageLocale.getLanguage(code: Locale.current.languageCode!)) and \(language.name ?? "foreign")... (\(filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count ?? 0))"
    }
    return prompt
}

var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.sorted(by: { $0.native ?? "" < $1.native ?? "" }) ?? [], id: \.self) { filteredMemoryPalaceThing in
            MemoryPalaceRowView(memoryPalaceThing: filteredMemoryPalaceThing, changeVoiceSpeed: changeVoiceSpeed ?? 0.25, numberSpeechLoops: numberSpeechLoops ?? 1)
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                Button {
                    viewContext.delete(filteredMemoryPalaceThing)
                    PersistenceController.shared.saveDB()
                } label: {
                    Image("deleteRow")
                }
                .tint(.red) 
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                Button {
                    if filteredMemoryPalaceThing.setAsHomework == false {
                        setHomework.setMemoryPalaceThingHomework(memoryPalaceThings: [filteredMemoryPalaceThing])
                    } else {
                        setHomework.unsetMemoryPalaceThingHomework(memoryPalaceThings: [filteredMemoryPalaceThing], memoryPalaces: Array(memoryPalaces))
                    }
                    PersistenceController.shared.saveDB()
                } label: {
                    if filteredMemoryPalaceThing.setAsHomework == false {
                        Image("addHomework")
                    } else {
                        Image("removeHomework")
                    }
                }
                .tint(homeworkColor.setHomeworkMemoryPalaceThing(memoryPalaceThing: filteredMemoryPalaceThing))
                
                Button {
                    self.memoryPalaceThing = filteredMemoryPalaceThing
                    self.editMemoryPalaceIsPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "edit")!)
                }
                .tint(Color.systemBlue)
                
                Button {
                    if filteredMemoryPalaceThing.selected == false {
                        let selectedMemoryPalaceThing = memoryPalaceThings.filter { $0.selected == true }
                        if selectedMemoryPalaceThing.count > 0 {
                            selectedMemoryPalaceThing[0].selected = false
                        }
                        let selectedSectionThing = sectionThings.filter { $0.selected == true }
                        if selectedSectionThing.count > 0 {
                            selectedSectionThing[0].selected = false
                        }
                        filteredMemoryPalaceThing.selected = true
                    }
                    PersistenceController.shared.saveDB()
                } label: {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "chooseCanvas")!)
                }
                .tint(self.canvasColor.setCanvasMemoryPalaceThing(memoryPalaceThing: filteredMemoryPalaceThing))
            }
        }
    }
    .onEmpty(for: memoryPalaceThings.filter{ $0.memoryPalace?.language == language && $0.memoryPalace == memoryPalace }.isEmpty, with: emptyDataMessage ?? NSMutableAttributedString())
    .searchable(text: $queryString, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: searchablePrompt)
    .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    .background(Color.init(.systemGroupedBackground))
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button(action: {
                self.nativeThing = ""
                self.foreignThing = ""
                self.addToMemoryPalaceIsPresented = true
            }, label: {
                Image("addRow").foregroundColor(Color.systemBlue)
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                if playEntireList {
                    self.playEntireList = false
                    aurotorial.stop(stopAt: "immediate")
                } else {
                    self.playEntireList = true
                    loopPlayList()
                }
            }, label: {
                if filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count ?? 0 <= 1 {
                    Image(self.playEntireList ? "stopPlayList" : "loopPlayList")
                } else {
                    Image(self.playEntireList ? "stopPlayList" : "loopPlayList").foregroundColor(Color.systemBlue)
                }
            })
            .disabled(filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count ?? 0 <= 1)
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            if selection.isEmpty {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("delete")
                }
                .disabled(true)
            } else {
                Button(action: { self.deleteMemoryPalaceThingIsPresented = true
                }, label: {
                    Image("delete").foregroundColor(.red)
                })
                .disabled(false)
            }
            
            if editMode == .inactive {
                Button(action: {
                    self.editMode = .active
                    self.selection = Set<MemoryPalaceThing>()
                }, label: {
                    if filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count == 0 {
                        Image("selectRows")
                    } else {
                        Image("selectRows").foregroundColor(Color.systemBlue)
                    }
                })
                .disabled(filteredMemoryPalaceThings?.count == 0)
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.editMode = .inactive
                    self.selection = Set<MemoryPalaceThing>()
                }) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: initialize)
```